# construct bigquery client without file but parsing the credentials directly

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use the google-cloud-bigquery package.

When I want to create a `Client` I can point to the path of a file e.g

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json("path/to/credentials/cred.json")
```

according to the [docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/2.21.0/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.from_service_account_info) I should be able to just parse the credentials directly using

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
creds = get_creds_as_string() #Returns the credentials as a string
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_info(creds)
```

but that raises

```
type object 'Client' has no attribute 'from_service_account_info'
```

which is odd since the method is described in the docs.

Is there a way to parse the credentials directly?

Comment: version difference?

Comment: I have checked that

Comment: They are Both 2.23.2